# jQuery UI .position() not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to set the position of `<span>` elements by using jQuery UI's `.position()` function, but I can't get it to work. I want them to be next to list elements of a sortable `<ul>`.

Here is my HTML structure:

```
<div id="#tabs-settings-wrapper">
    <p>You can order them by drag and drop.</p>
    <ul id="tabs-sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default tabs-sortable-item" id="tab-0" data-position="0">overview</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default tabs-sortable-item" id="tab-1" data-position="1">detail 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default tabs-sortable-item" id="tab-2" data-position="2">detail 2</li>
    </ul>

    <button id="tabs-add-new-button">Add new</button>

    <!-- These are created dynamically, see JavaScript below -->
    <span id="tab-0-remove-icon" class="tabs-remove-icon fa fa-trash fa-lg" data-position="0"></span>
    <span id="tab-1-remove-icon" class="tabs-remove-icon fa fa-trash fa-lg" data-position="1"></span>
    <span id="tab-2-remove-icon" class="tabs-remove-icon fa fa-trash fa-lg" data-position="2"></span>

</div>
```

and my JavaScript code:

```
 $(function () {
    $("#tabs-sortable").sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    });

    // add remove icons to every li
    $(".tabs-sortable-item").each(function () {
        var position = $(this).data("position");
        var id = "#" + $(this).prop("id");
        var removeIconID = '#tab-' + position + '-remove-icon';
        $('<span id="tab-' + position + '-remove-icon" class="tabs-remove-icon fa fa-trash fa-lg" data-position="' + position + '"></span>').appendTo("#tabs-settings-wrapper");
        $(removeIconID).position({
            my: "right",
            at: "left",
            of: id,
            collision: "none"
        });
    });

    $("#tabs-add-new-button").button().click(function () {
        // numbering seems strange, but is more human-like (and logical)
        var maxPosition = $(".tabs-sortable-item").length - 1;
        var newPosition = maxPosition + 1;

        $('<li class="ui-state-default tabs-sortable-item" id="tab-' + newPosition + '">' +
            '<input id="tabs-add-new-input" style="margin-top: -5px;" placeholder="Enter a name" />' +
        '</li>').appendTo("#tabs-sortable");

        $('<button class="tabs-add-new-save-button" id="tab-' + newPosition + '-save-button" data-position="' + newPosition + '">Save</button>').appendTo("#tabs-settings-wrapper");
        $("#tab-" + String(newPosition) + "-save-button").button();
        $("#tab-" + String(newPosition) + "-save-button").position({
            my: "left",
            at: "right+20px",
            of: "#tab-" + String(newPosition) + ""
        });

        $('<button class="tabs-add-new-cancel-button" id="tab-' + newPosition + '-cancel-button" data-position="' + newPosition + '">Cancel</button>').appendTo("#tabs-settings-wrapper");
        $("#tab-" + String(newPosition) + "-cancel-button").button();
        $("#tab-" + String(newPosition) + "-cancel-button").position({
            my: "left",
            at: "right+10px",
            of: "#tab-" + String(newPosition) + "-save-button"
        });

        var li = $("#tabs-sortable li");
        var innerWidth = li.innerWidth();
        var paddingLeft = li.css("padding-left").substring('p')[1];
        var paddingRight = li.css("padding-right").substring('p')[1];
        $(".tabs-sortable-item input").last().focus().css("width", (innerWidth - (paddingLeft + paddingRight)));

        $("#tabs-sortable").sortable("refresh");

        // prevent the user from adding multiple list items at once
        $("#tabs-add-new-button").button("disable");
    });

});
```

But they appear after the *add new* button (where they are written in the HTML code) and not where I expect them to:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I add two buttons on click on the *add new* button and positioning them seems to work. I added this code to the JavaScript section. This is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: I think that's more of a CSS problem

Comment: ok... But I have no clue what to try

Comment: It will be tricky to display correctly next to the `ul`. Why don't you put them in the `<li>` instead of using `position`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should avoid using `position` in this case, due to the `ul` list.

I would rather add a `span` in every `li` and update/hide it via code when necessary.

```
<div id="#tabs-settings-wrapper">
    <p>You can order them by drag and drop.</p>
    <ul id="tabs-sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default tabs-sortable-item" id="tab-0" data-position="0">
            overview 
            <span id="tab-0-remove-icon" class="tabs-remove-icon fa fa-trash fa-lg" data-position="0"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default tabs-sortable-item" id="tab-1" data-position="1">
            detail 1
            <span id="tab-1-remove-icon" class="tabs-remove-icon fa fa-trash fa-lg" data-position="1"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default tabs-sortable-item" id="tab-2" data-position="2">
            detail 2
            <span id="tab-2-remove-icon" class="tabs-remove-icon fa fa-trash fa-lg" data-position="2"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="tabs-add-new-button">Add new</button>
</div>
```

Or add the `span`s with code directly in the `li` (via `document.getElementById("tab-1").appendChild(span);` for example).

Comment: I considered this as well and I might end up with this version but I am adding two buttons on click on the _add new_ button and setting their positions seems to work. I will add this code to my question.

Comment: The challenge is to add stuff next to the list items

Comment: Actually I realized I need to use sortable `<div>` elements because I need to provide more information than a name. Thus I have to rethink the style which includes the position of the remove-icons. Thank you for trying to help me, though!